# How to tell WPF to convert target to my source type without IValueConverter

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I assume there is a way to tell WPF how to convert a string target to my source type without having to specify an IValueConverter. WPF will convert string to color, for example. I thought if my type supported an explicit conversion from string to my type, that this would be enough. But this did not work. Is there a way?

Comment: You could register a [TypeConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have to define a type converter for your type.  You can convert from your type to string simply by overriding ToString().  To go the other direction you need a type converter.  For example...

```
public class PartNumberConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if(value is string)
        {
            return new PartNumber(value as string);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
[TypeConverter(typeof(PartNumberConverter))]
public class PartNumber
{
    public PartNumber(string s)
    {
        string[] e = s.Split('-');
        if(e.Length==3)
        {
            _a = Convert.ToInt32(e[0]);
            _b = Convert.ToInt32(e[1]);
            _c = Convert.ToInt32(e[2]);
        }
    }
    public PartNumber(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        _c = c;
    }
    int _a = 0;
    int _b = 0;
    int _c = 0;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _a + "-" + _b + "-" + _c;
    }
}
```

So not a IValueConverter but still a converter :)

Comment: NOTE: for the OP's sake.  `IValueConverter` is a run-time tool.  The `TypeConverter` listed here is a design time tool.  If you are binding to your object directly, the `IValueConverter` may be the correct tool.  If you are creating an instance of your type in XAML, then the `TypeConverter` is the correct tool.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to have my typed used  by XAML programmers without having to creating a IValueConverter. This works perfectly. Thank you.